# How to add a category in the FAQ_ask module

Tags: 6

I am using the [FAQ Ask the Expert Module](http://drupal.org/project/faq) on my drupal 6.  I am not very familiar with the drupal interface and have trouble setting up modules. I would like my ask a question for to have categories in which the asker can check off. The question would then be sent to the expert corresponding with that category. 

 It seems like this is what this module would do except I cannot get the categories to show up. Can someone give me step by step instructions?

EDIT: I would like the categories to show up on this form:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the version for Drupal 6, or Drupal 7? I am asking because in Drupal 7, most of the menus have changed path, and the answer could change basing on the Drupal version to which you are interested.

Comment: I am using drupal 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use categories with the FAQ module you need to have the taxonomy module enabled.

Once you have the taxonomy module enabled you will need to create at least one vocabulary and associate it with the "FAQ" content type.

Once you've completed the above step you can visit the FAQ categories configuration page (admin/settings/faq/categories) and set up how you would like the categories to be display and there expected behavior on the faq page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you give me a screenshot of what the form looks like with categories or something? Because I'm sure I've configured it right but no categories are showing up :(

Comment: Can you be more specific? No categories are showing up on which form?

Comment: on the ask the expert form

Comment: Have you created your vocabulary? and their terms? and associated that vocabulary with the FAQ content type?

Comment: yes i have. are the categories supposed to show up on the forms?

Comment: yes, the categories will show up if they're enabled for that "FAQ" content type. You can enabled it over at admin/content/taxonomy/ and click the edit vocabulary link for the specific vocabulary you want to add. Once you're editing the vocabulary make sure that under content type "FAQ" is selected.

Comment: I have and the words are on the FAQ settings page. Its just not showing up on the form

Comment: Does it show up when you do add a regular FAQ page? over at node/add/faq

Comment: yes it does under vocabularies

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure. I'm seing everything with the standard configuration I would recommend checking the permissions and maybe try with the admin user to make sure its not a module issue or maybe css hiding them form or something silly. I would try updating the latest version but I'm not having any problems display the categories :-(

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what yours looks like? I have edited my question with a screenshot

Comment: Sure, here you go. http://imgur.com/ZVYwM.png

Comment: If I provide you with screenshots of my settings could you go through them see why they're not showing up? Thanks for all your time